# Collect all RPMs that are needed by a package to make a custom CentOS DVD

Tags: dependencies, rpm, yum

I need to copy all of the RPMs from a CentOS repo that are needed to build a custom version of CentOS for a DVD.

Essentially I need a complete list of the packages needed by my custom RPM so that I can copy them to the ISO image I am building.

I have a custom RPM(s) here that is not in the repo so I can't use yum deplist.

When I do rpm -qpR  it is close but it lists things that are not files with pathnames or packages.

Files are easy because I can loop with repoquery --qf='%{name}' -f file-name

Packages are easy too because they are what I need.

But I get dependencies from rpm -qpR like config(alsa-lib) and rtld(GNU_HASH)  which are neither packages nor files nor libraries.

I am considering just saying any dependency with a "(" in it, except empty '()' can be skipped. Will this work?

The empty '()' ones I would use repoquery to get the package since it would be a library.

Also I get dependencies like:
    libc.so.6()(64bit)
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.16)(64bit)
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
    . . .

Lots of different versions of GLIBC. I am thinking about just installing the newest one from my repo since glibc shows up as a package. Is this safe?

Comment: You're probably best asking this on Unix & Linux StackExchange (or similar) as it isn't really a programming question.

Comment: It's topical for [rpm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rpm), and this group gets more attention than [USE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rpm).

Answer (score 1):

There are several questions asked (you might consider refactoring your question).  Here are some answers:

- [repoquery](http://linux.die.net/man/1/repoquery) might be useful for deploying your application, but not much use for analyzing the set of needed RPMs.  For the use you are making of it, a plain "rpm -qf" for the given files will identify the package name, and do it more rapidly.
- the [manpage for `rpm`](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/rpm.8.html) is a good place to start.  It has the `-R` option: *List capabilities on which this package depends.*
- `rpm` also has `--whatprovides`: *Query all packages that provide the CAPABILITY capability.*.

Largely, your question seems to have overlooked *capabilities*.  Those may be specific files, or they may be names for other ways to refer to packages and/or their contents.  For instance, this:

```
$ rpm -qR `rpm -qf vi`
config(vim-minimal) = 2:7.4.629-5.el6
libacl.so.1()(64bit)  
libacl.so.1(ACL_1.0)(64bit)  
libc.so.6()(64bit)  
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11)(64bit)  
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)  
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit)  
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4)(64bit)  
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit)  
libselinux.so.1()(64bit)  
libtinfo.so.5()(64bit)  
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib(VersionedDependencies) <= 3.0.3-1
rtld(GNU_HASH)  
rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1
```

Those lines are *capabilities*, e.g.,

```
$ rpm -q --whatprovides 'libtinfo.so.5()(64bit)'
ncurses-libs-5.7-4.20090207.el6.x86_64
```

To accomplish your task, you should follow those capabilities recursively, until you reach (and presumably disregard) packages in the base system.  Some packages provide multiple capabilities:

```
$ rpm -q --whatprovides 'config(vim-minimal) = 2:7.4.629-5.el6'
no package provides config(vim-minimal) = 2:7.4.629-5.el6
$ rpm -q --whatprovides 'libacl.so.1()(64bit)'
libacl-2.2.49-6.el6.x86_64
$ rpm -q --whatprovides 'libacl.so.1(ACL_1.0)(64bit)'
libacl-2.2.49-6.el6.x86_64
$ rpm -q --whatprovides 'libc.so.6()(64bit)'
glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64
$ rpm -q --whatprovides 'libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11)(64bit)'
glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64 
$ rpm -q --whatprovides 'libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)'
glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64
$ rpm -q --whatprovides 'libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit)'
glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64       
$ rpm -q --whatprovides 'libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4)(64bit)'
glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64
$ rpm -q --whatprovides 'libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit)'
glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64
$ rpm -q --whatprovides 'libselinux.so.1()(64bit)'
libselinux-2.0.94-5.8.el6.x86_64
$ rpm -q --whatprovides 'libtinfo.so.5()(64bit)'
ncurses-libs-5.7-4.20090207.el6.x86_64
$ rpm -q --whatprovides 'rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1'
no package provides rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1                      
$ rpm -q --whatprovides 'rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1'
no package provides rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
$ rpm -q --whatprovides 'rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1'
no package provides rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
$ rpm -q --whatprovides 'rpmlib(VersionedDependencies) <= 3.0.3-1'
no package provides rpmlib(VersionedDependencies) <= 3.0.3-1
$ rpm -q --whatprovides 'rtld(GNU_HASH)'
glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64
$ rpm -q --whatprovides 'rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1'
no package provides rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1
```

The "no package provides" hint at special cases which this option does not address.  See for instance the situation with `rpmlib` discussed in *[Re: rpmlib(VersionedDependencies) <= 3.0.3-1](https://www.redhat.com/archives/rpm-list/2001-April/msg00283.html)*, which says that `rpm --showrc` provides the information.  (The vim-minimal warning is another special case -- you will handle it and others as they come up).

It is not necessary to install an RPM to find what capabilities it provides.  You can do that using the `--provides` option, e.g.,

```
rpm -qp --provides your-package-name.rpm
```

and (as you noted before) use the `-R` option to see what a given package *requires*:

```
rpm -qpR your-package-name.rpm
```

Looking at a package I built for [ncurses-examples](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-examples.html), those two commands give me

```
$ rpm -qp  --provides ncurses-examples-6.0-20151107.x86_64.rpm 
ncurses-examples = 6.0-20151107
ncurses-examples(x86-64) = 6.0-20151107

$ rpm -qpR ncurses-examples-6.0-20151107.x86_64.rpm
libc.so.6()(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit)
libformw6.so.6()(64bit)
libformw6.so.6(NCURSESW6_5.1.20000708)(64bit)
libformw6.so.6(NCURSESW6_5.9.20150530)(64bit)
libm.so.6()(64bit)
libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
libmenuw6.so.6()(64bit)
libmenuw6.so.6(NCURSESW6_5.1.20000708)(64bit)
libncursesw6.so.6()(64bit)
libncursesw6.so.6(NCURSESW6_5.1.20000708)(64bit)
libncursesw6.so.6(NCURSESW6_5.3.20021019)(64bit)
libncursesw6.so.6(NCURSESW6_5.4.20040208)(64bit)
libncursesw6.so.6(NCURSESW6_5.7.20081102)(64bit)
libpanelw6.so.6()(64bit)
libpanelw6.so.6(NCURSESW6_5.1.20000708)(64bit)
libtinfow6.so.6()(64bit)
libtinfow6.so.6(NCURSES6_TINFO_5.0.19991023)(64bit)
libtinfow6.so.6(NCURSES6_TINFO_5.1.20000708)(64bit)
libtinfow6.so.6(NCURSES6_TINFO_5.4.20040208)(64bit)
libtinfow6.so.6(NCURSES6_TINFO_5.7.20081102)(64bit)
libtinfow6.so.6(NCURSES6_TINFO_5.9.20150530)(64bit)
libutil.so.1()(64bit)
libutil.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1
rtld(GNU_HASH)
```

Like libc6, the ncurses6 ABI has versions to account for, and just matching `()` alone will not necessarily get the right version of a library.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for your thoughts and extra explanation for capabilities.

Unfortunately I can't use rpm -qf or --whatprovides because those don't look in my custom repo. I may even be running my ISO build script on a version of Linux different from the version I am using to build the ISO.

I wonder what the heck distros do when they build an ISO. They need to solve this problem too. Perhaps they install the version on a machine/VM and use rpm but installing things to find out dependencies seems like it should be unnecessary and slow.

Comment: If you have a ".repo" file in `/etc/yum.repos.d` pointing to your local repository, yum can do that.  It relies upon connecting via a web service.  Start with the [`createrepo`](http://createrepo.baseurl.org/) command.

Comment: Yes I have have a repo file in /etc/yum.repos.d. I refer to it with my repoquery commands for example. But I don't have the custom RPM in my repo. The custom RPM is just for the DVD ISO.