# It's possible to create an executable binary from a RHEL6 .RPM file and dependences?

Tags: binaryfiles, rpm

There is an Red Hat EL06 server on which I need to "install" a package that is not part of the official repository.
So far so good, I'd download the .rpm file manually, I'd satisfy the dependencies and I'd install.
The problem is that I do not have access to root and the administrator does not install packages that are not official.

However, if I have a binary with execution permission in my home dir, I will be able to execute and my need will be met.

So I ask, is it possible to generate a directory containing all dependencies of libs + binary executable, starting from an RPM file? How do you do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract the contents of an rpm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18787375/how-do-i-extract-the-contents-of-an-rpm)

Comment: Unsure if this is a duplicate per se, but definitely feel that question could get the asker to a solution that works for him.

Comment: No, It doesn't. In that post explains how to extracts the content from a RPM file and what I needs to know how to create a binary (executable) file from RPM and yours dependences.

Comment: @Michel mention that you would satisfy the dependencies. Once, dependencies are satisfied. You can extract the binary files from rpm and use it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Collect all RPMs that are needed by a package to make a custom CentOS DVD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33703058/collect-all-rpms-that-are-needed-by-a-package-to-make-a-custom-centos-dvd)